# Finding corresponding node in a duplicate binary-tree

Tags: algorithms

Given two duplicate binary trees (see the embedded picture), you are given a node in Tree A, find the same corresponding node in Tree B.

I believe the optimal approach should be traversing both trees at the same time, and when you reached the node in Tree A, you would know you have also reached the same node in Tree B.

Code example to solve this issue would be appreciated.

[image: duplicate binary tree]

Comment: I'm not very sure about other constraints. But depending on scenario keeping track of pointers to each node in hashtable indexed by key_values would work.

Comment: Is the binary tree a BST?

Comment: As usual, *optimal* is meaningless as long as you don't give an evaluation criterion.

Comment: Please describe the tree implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide a code example. 
Your approach would work, and takes time proportional to the *size* of the tree (i.e., its number of vertices) in the worst-case. This can be improved to only take worst-case time proportional to the depth of the vertex of interest.
If the tree is balanced, there would be an exponential difference in the running times.

Keep track of the path from the node of interest to the root $r$ of Tree $A$. In particular, for each node  $x \neq r$ of the path, push into a stack $S$ either $L$ or $R$ depending whether $x$ it is the left or right child of its parent.

Then, start from the root of Tree $B$, iteratively pop from a value $y$ from $S$ and move to the left or right child depending on whether $y=L$ or $y=R$, respectively. The node you're at when the stack is empty is exactly the node you're looking for.

Comment: Wouldn’t you need to do Bfs/Dfs from the root of $A$ to find the path to $y$?

Comment: Not really. After after the whole path from $x$ to $r$ has been traversed you have its structure (all "left" and "right" turns from the root) stored into the stack $S$. You just need to replay these turns starting from the root of tree $B$. This takes time proportional to $|S|$, i.e., to the length of the path. There is no need to visit any other vertex in $B$-

Comment: That assumes you have a pointer to the parent for each node as well, correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. That assumes each node has a pointer to its children and to its parent.

Comment: I don't see how the fact that the tree is balanced could influence the traversal time at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. If the tree is balanced then any path from a vertex to the root has length $O(\log n)$. Notice than I'm not doing a full traversal of the tree, just climbing from the given node to the root in tree A, and then retracing the (reverse of) the path on tree B.

Comment: @Steven: I mean that for an exhaustive search, balancing is unimportant. And for the upward path tracing, what matters is the depth, not the balancing.

Comment: Agreed. I'm using upward path tracing, balancing is a sufficient condition to ensure that the height (and hence the depth of every node) is logarithmic. Maybe it is the "this can be improved" part that is confusing? I didn't mean that the traversal can be implemented in a faster way, but that there is a faster approach than traversal (i.e., upward path tracing, described immediately after) and this can result in an exponential speedup (whenever the depth of the node is logarithmic, which, e.g., happens in any balanced tree).

Answer (score 0):

If upward links are available, trace the path from $n_A$ to the root $r_A$, then trace back from $r_B$ to $n_B$. Otherwise, traverse $A$ until you find $n_A$ (using your favorite method), while keeping a trace of the path, or performing the same moves in $B$.

Note that a path can be represented as a mere bit string telling left or right on every level. (A foolish solution could even avoid storing the bit when a node has a single child.)

The first method requires a string as long as the depth of $n_A$ (used as a LIFO queue). It can be implemented recursively for this purpose.

The second method requires a string as long as the deepest depth reached during the traversal (FIFO queue).

The third does not need a representation of the path.